# What happens in Git when adding origin?

Tags: git, git-remote

What does Git exactly do when we add an `origin`?

Is it like saying we are creating a new repository? How different it is from `push`?

Comment: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html

Comment: You've got a lot of questions about Git. I recommend reading [ProGit](http://git-scm.com/book); I found it very useful when I was starting out.

Answer (score 3):

Traditionally, `origin` is just the default name assigned to a remote repository when you clone it:

```
git clone git@some.server.com:some/repo.git
```

will result in having

```
origin  git@some.server.com:some/repo.git (fetch)
origin  git@some.server.com:some/repo.git (push)
```

as the output of `git remote -v`.

Alternatively, if you want to be able to push/pull to/from another remote repository, you can do:

```
git remote add git@another.server.com:another/repo.git whatever
```

and receive

```
origin  git@some.server.com:some/repo.git (fetch)
origin  git@some.server.com:some/repo.git (push)
whatever    git@another.server.com:another/repo.git (fetch)
whatever    git@another.server.com:another/repo.git (push)
```

from `git remote -v`.

After that you'll be able to do both `git push origin master` and `git push whatever master`.